# OLED shield for wemos d1 mini pro not staying on

Tags: arduino-uno, esp8266

I recently bought a wemos d1 mini pro to toy with wifi and bought a oled shield with it. I've been looking on youtube and github for software and I finally found the software and got it to load onto the board. however, the shield is only on for a fraction of a second and I don't know why.

here is the code

```
#include "SPI.h"
#include "Wire.h"
#include "Adafruit_GFX.h"
#include "Adafruit_SSD1306.h"

#define OLED_RESET 0  // GPIO0
Adafruit_SSD1306 display(OLED_RESET);

void setup()   {
Serial.begin(9600);

display.begin(SSD1306_SWITCHCAPVCC, 0x3C); 
// init done

display.display();
delay(2000);

// Clear the buffer.
display.clearDisplay();

// text display tests
display.setTextSize(2);
display.setTextColor(WHITE);
display.setCursor(0,10);
display.println("Hello");
display.println("World");

display.display();
delay(10000);
display.clearDisplay();
}


void loop() {

}
```

here is what it says when uploading

```
Build options changed, rebuilding all
Sketch uses 278084 bytes (26%) of program storage space. Maximum is 1044464 
bytes.
Global variables use 27432 bytes (33%) of dynamic memory, leaving 54488 
bytes for local variables. Maximum is 81920 bytes.
esptool.py v2.6
2.6
esptool.py v2.6
Serial port COM5
Connecting....
Chip is ESP8266EX
Features: WiFi
MAC: b4:e6:2d:53:19:6b
Uploading stub...
Running stub...
Stub running...
Changing baud rate to 460800
Changed.
Configuring flash size...
Auto-detected Flash size: 16MB
Flash params set to 0x0290
Compressed 282240 bytes to 204639...

Writing at 0x00000000... (7 %)
Writing at 0x00004000... (15 %)
Writing at 0x00008000... (23 %)
Writing at 0x0000c000... (30 %)
Writing at 0x00010000... (38 %)
Writing at 0x00014000... (46 %)
Writing at 0x00018000... (53 %)
Writing at 0x0001c000... (61 %)
Writing at 0x00020000... (69 %)
Writing at 0x00024000... (76 %)
Writing at 0x00028000... (84 %)
Writing at 0x0002c000... (92 %)
Writing at 0x00030000... (100 %)
Wrote 282240 bytes (204639 compressed) at 0x00000000 in 4.8 seconds 
(effective 467.5 kbit/s)...
Hash of data verified.

Leaving...
Hard resetting via RTS pin...
```

and this is the monitor

```
0⸮~?⸮4⸮!⸮⸮⸮⸮OCAG⸮⸮
```

thank you for your time

Comment: How is it all being powered?

Comment: through a usb from my computer

Comment: you set io 0 as reset. to which D pin on the board did you wire the reset pin of the display? D0 (io 16) or D3 (io 0)?

Comment: did you try to remove the last two lines of setup()?

Comment: I assume I wired the reset pin to the reset pin on the wemos mini pro due having soldered all 16 male pins on the oled shield going into all 16 female pins on the top half of the wemos mini pro. I did remove the cleardisplay() line but not the second to last. I'll try that tomorrow morning

Comment: sorry. It is a shield so you don't wire it. I found the schematics

Comment: i tried removing the last 2 lines from the setup code but it did nothing. I also have a dc power shield which i just tried and it doesn't help

Answer (score -1):

I fixed the problem. I was the one who did the soldering so i decided to make the soldering better and now it works. thank you juraj for your time